# Using DateTime.Now with ASCII encoding to populate a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime, encoding, ascii

I'm trying to fill a byte array with the current date and time, in the following format: YYMMDDHHmm.
However, DateTime.Now.Day or DateTime.Now.Month or any of these methods return ints, which eventually causes null reference exceptions in my code (when a "day" value is smaller than 10, for instance, there won't be a second byte to reference).

```
        DATETIME[0] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())[2];
        DATETIME[1] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())[3];
        DATETIME[2] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString())[0];
        DATETIME[3] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString())[1];
        DATETIME[4] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString())[0];
        DATETIME[5] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString())[1];
        DATETIME[6] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString())[0];
        DATETIME[7] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString())[1];
        DATETIME[8] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString())[0];
        DATETIME[9] = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString())[1];
```

This is probably gonna be something stupid, but does anybody has any idea of how to get the right values inside the byte array this without using a bunch of if's?

For example: 11/01/17 08:46 -> [49][55][49][49][48][49][48][56][52][54] (in ASCII encoding)

Comment: Put fomrat into ToString method : ToString("yyMMddhhmm")

Comment: Side note: I'd strongly suggest that you call `DateTime.Now` once and store the result in a local variable. Consider what happens if one (or more) of those components move to a new value *while* your code is in the middle of its work.

Comment: @jdweng worked like a charm! Thanks a lot friend

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever indeed, it could be considered. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhhmm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0:s}",DateTime.Now));

or something similar, that format gives: "2008-03-09T16:05:07" so a bit of tweaking should fix it to your style.

Comment: Use "String.Format ("{0:dd}/{0:MM}/{0:yyyy} {0:hh}:{0:mm}", DateTime.Now)" to get the format you're wanting.